# Want to scroll a DIV element, not entire webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

Long story short, I need to figure out a quick way to scroll a div element from the JavaScript console in Google Chrome. Here is a picture of the element that I am trying to scroll:

http://i1250.photobucket.com/albums/hh527/dr4g1116/Capture_zps63402209.png

And here is the HTML where the DIV item is that I need to scroll (highlighted at the top):

http://i1250.photobucket.com/albums/hh527/dr4g1116/Capture1_zps04c66647.png

Here's what I've tried so far:

First:

```
<NestedList_trends_trends_variable_selector_variable_selector_variable.scrollTo>(0,250)
```

Next:

```
NestedList_trends_trends_variable_selector_variable_selector_variable.scrollTo(0,250)
```

Finally:

```
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#NestedList_trends_trends_variable_selector_variable_selector_variable').offset().top}, 5000)
```

This last one just scrolled the entire page. Not sure why as I referred to the correct DIV ID.

I've tried tweaking any of these three methods, but to no avail. I've run out of ideas and nothing I find on the web has helped me. Anyone have any ideas on how I can scroll this element? Please let me know!

Thanks and cheers!!

**UPDATE:**

Tried this to no avail:

```
$('#NestedList_trends_trends_variable_selector_variable_selector_variable').animate({ scrollTop: $('#Button_86').offset().top}, 5000)
```

Comment: do you have weird `id` choice syndrome, or something?

Comment: try `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".NestedList").offset().top }, 5000);`  , taken from http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/01/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin/

Comment: @Connor - no, this is legacy software and I'm writing tests for them. I cannot change the ID.

Comment: @DomDay - thank you so much for the suggestion. It didn't work, but I can try manipulating it as I have manipulated my other code.

Answer (score 0):

You are animating the body element. You need to animate the target div. Also, I would consider either shortening the ID on that element to make it more manageable or target the element using one of the classes. Either way, try using the code in that last snippet but put the nested list inside of the first selector and the child element to which you want to scroll in the scrollTop attribute's selector.

Comment: Gave that a shot, but still didn't work. Thank you for the suggestion. See my update as to how I did it. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have jQuery so this should do:

`$("#NestedList_trends_trends_variable_selector_variable_selector_variable").scrollTop(250);`

or to make my brain stop hurting:

```
//somewhere at top of file or in a bloody config somewhere
var bigAssIdDiv = $("#NestedList_trends_trends_variable_selector_variable_selector_variable");
...
///later
bigAssIdDiv.scrollTop(250);
```

Note that with scrollTop the number you provide is the number of pixels "hidden" above the top (similar to scrolling down by that number of pixels...)